# How to use category image in detail page?

Tags: magento-2.1, category, phtml, product-view

I need to display relevant category image alongside product detail page. I need to display product's sub category image. Im using custom phtml file to display logo image on top of/before the product name. (image location)

My categories are like this,
Category one
Category two
Category three

each category has a few manufacturers as sub categories. I need to display that manufacturer logo image on product's detail page.

I tried using module_catelog/templates/category/image.phtml but it shows some errors on this line of code.

```
$_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()
```

How can I get the category image URL in my phtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update template files to show the manufacturer(s) logo.

Open `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

**=> If you want to display manufacturer image:**

```
<?php 
     $_product = $this->getProduct();
     $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
     $manufacturerId = $_product->getManufacturer();
     echo '<a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]='.$manufacturerId.'">' ?>
     <img src="../media/catalog/brands/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_',$manufacturerName); ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $manufacturerName; ?>" /></a>
```

Manufacturer images in this example are relative to `/media/catalog/brands/`

**=> If you want to Display Category Image :**

```
<?php $categoryImage = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail(); //Get the file name of the Image stored for the category ?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$categoryImage  ?>" />
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks. Another question I have. Is there any other way to set images of manufacturer rather than using media/catalog/brands folder? may be something like using CMS block for each manufacturer or something dynamic so someone who has no knowledge on magento code, can add/change images from backend?

Comment: plus Mage is deprecated in magento 2. so this part "=>  Display Category Image " cannot be implemented in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

```
If(Mage::registry('current_catgory')){
    $Cat=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_catgory'));
    $name=$Cat->getName();
    $thum=  Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$Cat->getData('thumbnail');
}
```

This code is work if you coming to product page from category page.

Comment: Thanks. "Mage" is deprecated in magento 2. So I cant use this. what if user comes from search result? or suggested product? my requirements is to show manufacturer image no matter which path user came from